# Couchbase unique users count per day/month etc

Tags: count, mapreduce, unique, couchbase

I'm quite new in CouchBase and Map/reduce logic. What I'm trying to create is a view where I can see the unique users per day/month/year/hour and per day/month/year

for example lets assume that we have the following JSON documents inserted:

```
{
  uid:"user1",
  time: "2013/12/24 18:45"
  city:"London"
  event:"open"
},

{
  uid:"user1",
  time: "2013/12/24 18:46"
  city:"London"
  event:"open"
},

{
  uid:"user2",
  time: "2013/12/24 18:46"
  city:"London"
  event:"open"
}
```

So my desired result I wanted to be:

```
{time:"2013-12-24 18:45", count:1}
{time:"2013-12-24 18:46", count:2}
{time:"2013-12-24 18", count:2} // user1 is considered as uniqu within the hour and counted once
```

I have tried the following:

**map**

```
function (doc, meta) {
     // date of document   
     var date = new Date(doc.time);

     // Granularity   
     var day = date.getDate();
     var month = date.getMonth();
     var year = date.getFullYear();
     var hour = date.getHours();
     var min = date.getMinutes();

     emit([year, month, day, hour, min], {user: doc.uid, count:1});   
     emit([year, month, day, hour], {user:doc.uid, count:1});   
}
```

**Reduce**

```
function(key, values, rereduce){
  if(rereduce) return;

  var users = {user: "", count: 0 };

  values.forEach(function(v) {
    for(var k in v) {
      if(!users[k])
        users[k] = 0

      users[k] += v[k];
    }
  });

  return(users);

}
```

**I have two problems:**

When I run in in the **development** mode everything is ok and i get back the following result(skipped some lines to beutify the result):

```
{"rows":[
{"key":[2013,11,19,18],"value":{"user":"00user9...skipped...","count":229}},
{"key":[2013,11,19,18,24],"value":{"user":"00user244user9...skipped...","count":228}},
{"key":[2013,11,19,18,25],"value":{"user":"0user804","count":1}}
]
}
```

but if I run it in full_set i get back an error:

```
from:
http://127.0.0.1:8092/thomas/_design/dev_uusers/_view/uunsers_per_day?    full_set=true&group=true&stale=false&connection_timeout=60000&limit=10&skip=0
reason:
error (function_clause)
```

And second is there a better way to **not** return the user id because in millions of users this will become very memory intense as the *user* value will become very big, right?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following doesn't reduce very well but but it works for me with about 3 million records  and will give you the aggregation based on time periods with only one emit, where
group_level=1 for  by year
group_level=2 for  by month
group_level=3 for  by day etc.

**map**

```
function (doc, meta) {
    // date of document   
    var date = new Date(doc.time);

    // Granularity   
    var day = date.getDate();
    var month = date.getMonth()+1;
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    var hour = date.getHours();
    var min = date.getMinutes();
    var obj ={};
    obj[doc.uid] = 1;
}
```

**reduce**

```
function (key, values, rereduce) {

    var userids = {};

    function collate(values) {
        for (userid in values) {
            if (userids[userid])
              userids[userid] +=values[userid]
            else
              userids[userid] =values[userid]
        }
    }
    values.forEach(function(partial) {
        collate(partial)
    }); 

    return userids; 
}
```

Unfortunately further reduction is beyond my grey cells, still you can reduce your memory usage if you return arrays instead of object and if you use group_level sensibly it might work well.

Answer (score 0):

What does the log file mapreduce_errors say? (You can find the file here /opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/logs )

I'm guessing you are going to be seeing 'reduction_too_long' messages.  Take a look at the following issues, perhaps they will help:

http://www.couchbase.com/issues/browse/MB-7047?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:worklog-tabpanel

or here: http://www.couchbase.com/forums/thread/newbie-question

If you include more information from the logs I'll be better able to help :)